# Postgres SUM over given time

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sum, aggregate-functions

I am trying to SUM google analytics data over a given time using Postgres. I am not quite sure how to get around a grouping issue. The query you see below returns one column per day. I want to SUM all clicks over the given dates. So the query should return 1 row for each campaign with a column on each row indicating the sum of clicks.

```
SELECT
    sa.id AS salesforce_account_id,
    acp.campaignid,
    acp.campaignname,
    date,     
    SUM(clicks) as clicks
FROM
    adwords_campaign_performance acp
INNER JOIN salesforce_account sa ON
    sa.adwords_id = acp.adwords_customerid
WHERE acp.date >= '2020-10-01'
  AND acp.date <= '2020-10-03'
GROUP BY sa.id, acp.campaignid, acp.campaignname, date
```

I can write the query so that it returns the number for the entire month as seen below:

```
SELECT
    sa.id AS salesforce_account_id,
    acp.campaignid,
    acp.campaignname,
     date_trunc('month', date) AS MONTH,
        SUM(clicks) as clicks
FROM
    adwords_campaign_performance acp
INNER JOIN salesforce_account sa ON
    sa.adwords_id = acp.adwords_customerid
WHERE MONTH = '2020-10-01 00:00:00'
  AND sa.id = 3148
GROUP BY sa.id, acp.campaignid, acp.campaignname, MONTH
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The query you see below returns one column per day. I want to SUM all clicks over the given dates. So the query should return 1 row for each campaign with a column on each row indicating the sum of clicks.

So just remove the `date` from the `select` and `group by` clauses:

```
SELECT
    sa.id AS salesforce_account_id,
    acp.campaignid,
    acp.campaignname,     
    SUM(clicks) as clicks
FROM adwords_campaign_performance acp
INNER JOIN salesforce_account sa ON sa.adwords_id = acp.adwords_customerid
WHERE acp.date >= '2020-10-01'
  AND acp.date <= '2020-10-03'
GROUP BY sa.id, acp.campaignid, acp.campaignname
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `generate_series()` to generate all days in the month:

```
SELECT gs.date, sa.id AS salesforce_account_id, acp.campaignid, acp.campaignname,
       SUM(clicks) as clicks
FROM generate_series('2020-10-01'::date, '2020-10-31'::date, interval '1 day') gs(dte) LEFT JOIN
     adwords_campaign_performance acp
     ON acp.date >= gs.dte AND
        acp.date < gs.dte + INTERVAL '1 DAY' LEFT JOIN 
     salesforce_account sa
     ON sa.adwords_id = acp.adwords_customerid
GROUP BY gs.dte, sa.id, acp.campaignid, acp.campaignname, date
```